# what is the source for the code coverage value picked by the jenkins plugin github-pr-coverage-status-plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, sonarqube

We are using GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin to trigger a build on PR and currently managed to post the test results and we are trying to post code coverage as well from sonarQube.
I have jacoco code coverage report generated.
After build completion, code coverage updated as a comment in gitHub. But not able to understand which value it picked to update the code coverage.
When I click on the code coverage comment in gitHub:
Jacoco Coverage Summary
[image]
Sonarqube coverage:
[image]

gitHub Comment:
[image]

In console build coverage build coverage: 0.19452723
How to find on what basis the build coverage calculated?